# Altering XML file format in C#

Tags: c#, xml, formatting

I have a program in Visual Studio which gives the output in an XML file. It looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<leaCEDS>
  <district>
    <leaID>01</leaID>
    <name>Alachua</name>
    <organizationType>LEA</organizationType>
    <streetLine1>620 E University Ave</streetLine1>
    <city>Gainesville</city>
    <stateProvince>FL</stateProvince>
    <postalCode>326015448</postalCode>
    <county>Alachua</county>
    <NCESID_district>1200030</NCESID_district>
    <date_created>2015-06-01T20:38:58.9730000</date_created>
    <date_updated>2015-06-01T20:38:58.9730000</date_updated>
  </district>
</leaCEDS>
```

I have now been told that I need to have the output for the XML file saved in this format..

```
<leaCEDS xlmns="http://specification.sifassociation.org/Implementation/na/3.2/html/CEDS/K12/K12_leaCEDS.html#LinkD">
    <districtEntry>
        <identification>
            <leaId>0001</leaId>
            <name>Alachua County Public Schools</name>
            <organizationType>LEA</organizationType>
        </identification>
        <addressList>
            <address>
                <street>
                    <line1>620 East University Avenue</line1>
                    <line2></line2>
                </street>
                <city>Gainsville</city>
                <stateProvince>FL</stateProvince>
                <postalCode>32601-5448</postalCode>
                <county>Alachua</county>
            </address>
        </addressList>
        <district>
            <reference>
                <NCESID>1200030</NCESID>
            </reference>
        </district>
    </districtEntry>
<leaCEDS>
```

How would I do this? I have tried looking up some solutions but haven't really found anything. Maybe a solution is using XSLT? I honestly don't believe that what i am being asked for is proper XML file format but it's something I must do.

Here is what my program looks like for clarification.

[image: XML Program]

Comment: Yes, this is the sort of thing XSLT was made for.  But it's a whole language of its own, so be prepared to spend some time learning.

Comment: If you have an existing program that is already producing an XML file couldn't you just study how the code is producing that XML and then modify it to do what you are looking for?

Comment: Oh!  This is what I get for not reading carefully.  Definitely, if you control the program that writes the output, just save it in the new format as @BryanHarrington suggests.

Comment: @BryanHarrington The program is using Xdocument / executeXMLreader to read the output from a database query, then streamwriter to write the file. I don't see anywhere I could alter the output.

Comment: @adv12 hope my last comment helps.

Comment: How is it using `XDocument` to create the output?

Comment: @CharlesMager

`using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
         var doc = Xdocument.Load(reader)
         using (var writer = new Streamwriter( ))
                 doc.Save(writer)`
basically like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your XML is coming straight from your database, which means you need to transform it into something else based on the structure you have presently.

While you could learn XSLT, you could also do this using LINQ to XML, querying the document you have parsed in order to get the contents required for your new format.  For example:

```
var d = doc.Descendants("district").Single();

XNamespace ns = "http://specification.sifassociation.org/Implementation/na/3.2/html/CEDS/K12/K12_leaCEDS.html#LinkD";

var transform = new XDocument(
    new XElement(ns + "leaCDS",
        new XElement(ns + "districtEntry",
            new XElement(ns + "identification",
                new XElement(ns + "leaID", (string)d.Element("leaID")),
                new XElement(ns + "name", (string)d.Element("name")),
                new XElement(ns + "organizationType", (string)d.Element("organizationType"))
                ),
            new XElement(ns + "addressList",
                new XElement(ns + "address",
                    new XElement(ns + "street",
                        new XElement(ns + "line1", (string)d.Element("streetLine1")),
                        new XElement(ns + "line2")
                        ),
                    new XElement(ns + "city", (string)d.Element("city")),
                    new XElement(ns + "stateProvince", (string)d.Element("stateProvince")),
                    new XElement(ns + "postalCode", (string)d.Element("postalCode")),
                    new XElement(ns + "county", (string)d.Element("county"))
                    )
                ),
            new XElement(ns + "district",
                new XElement(ns + "reference",
                    new XElement(ns + "NCESID", (string)d.Element("NCESID_district"))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

transform.Save(writer);
```

See a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZM27LX

Comment: Would I loop this if I had more than 1 district entry? Also, I see that you hard code the xml into `var xml`. Would i just load a file using `XDocument.Load`  then use the transform like you have shown?

Comment: The code above is what you'd use - this assume `doc` already exists as it does in your code in the comments to your question.  If you have more than one `district` then yes, you'd need to loop through the ones in the source document.

Comment: `var d = doc.Descendants("district").Single();` it gives an error on this line.
"Sequence contains more than one element". I might be using the code in the wrong place. I posted what my code looks like in the OP.

Comment: `Single`, as the name suggests, gets a single item. If there are 0 or >1 it will throw an exception.  If you have multiple districts you should iterate through them.

Comment: Oh, i understand about `Single` now. 
so would it be something like `foreach(doc.Descendants("district").Single())`

`var d = doc.Descendants("district").Single()`

? my bad if i'm confusing you, I am still getting the hang of C# syntax.

Comment: No, as `Single` will throw an exception as you've already worked out.  You need to iterate all districts returned by `doc.Descendants("district")` - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/GfwFcn for an example of how you might do that.